# How to add applications to startup that are using sudo to start?

Tags: scripts, sudo, startup

I have some applications that require `sudo` to start. I am being asked for password every time I start them.

How can I add them to startup with `sudo` without being asked for password?

Comment: It depends. What kind of application ? GUI or command-line ?

Answer (score 1):

You could create a new file in `/etc/sudoers.d` with the following line/s to your needs.

`exampleuser123 ALL=(root) NOPASSWD: /path/to/executable`

This should actually remove your need to a password and start the application as root. However see that as a security leak since you could create a new script file, name it and place it in that folder and execute it with root rights without the need for a password.

Comment: I am okay with sudo password when I use command line. I just want to know how to add applications that require sudo to startup.